# Sorting services in Linux

Tags: linux, bash

I have a few Linux servers, all running different services. When I run `service --status-all`, I get a couple screens of output. I thought I'd be smart and pipe it to `sort`, and see as a group what services are started, not started, or unknown. I executed the command, but it only sorted the `[ ? ]` entries at the top, and all the `[ - ]` and `[ + ]` entries are all clumped together in one mess!

The command I used was `service --status-all | sort`. Is there a better way to also sort the Plus and Minus signs?

This is specifically on a Debian box, running just the command line

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that `service --status-all` writes the `[ + ]` and `[ - ]` results to stdout but the `[ ? ]` results to stderr. Therefore, to use `sort` to sort all of them, you'll have to combine the stdout and stderr streams like this:

```
service --status-all 2>&1 | sort
```

Sorting is affected by the value of `LC_COLLATE`, which by default is the same as your `LANG` setting. If you don't want to change the value of `LC_COLLATE` for all your applications but do want this list sorted by `+`, `-` and `?`, then use this command instead:

```
service --status-all 2>&1 | LC_COLLATE=C sort
```

To set `LC_COLLATE` for all your applications, put this in your `~/.profile`, `~/.bash_profile`, or whatever script is sourced to set your environment at login:

```
export LC_COLLATE=C
```

Comment: Just tried, it didn't sort the output at all :(

Comment: I tested it on my Ubuntu 10.04 system before I posted and it sorted all the +'s first, then the -'s, then the ?'s. If it isn't working for you, it could be your LC_COLLATE setting.  Mine is "C". I just tried setting it to "en_US.UTF-8" and it then didn't sort for me, either, so that must be it. Try executing `LC_COLLATE=C`, then try sorting again.

Comment: Added output to my question (too long for a comment)

Comment: You didn't export LC_COLLATE. I forgot to mention that part.

Comment: OK, that works. I don't think I've had to do that before